# Won't sonic booms prevent Space X's BFR intercity transport plan from being acceptable?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, noise, hypersonic

Considering that Space X have just announced that their BFR can take anyone anywhere in the world in under 1 hour, that would be enormous speed, does this rocket not produce sonic boom?  If not is it because of its shape and that it does not have wings? Will it ever be allowed to fly across the US above the oceans and anywhere at those speeds considering again sonic boom?

Comment: hundreds of satellites cross the oceans and continents at this moment, at enormous speeds. Yet nobody complains about sonic booms.

Comment: Why worry about sonic booms?  Consider the launch noise.  Then figure that when you launch from anywhere the noise would be acceptable (KFC or Vandenberg, in the US), it would likely take you as long or longer to get there and board the rocket, than it would to go directly to your destination.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't know about you, but I can get to KSC much faster than I can get to, say, Hong Kong. And, like most of the world's population, I can get to KFC much faster than to either of those locations. :)

Comment: Please tell me this stands for Big F***** Rocket.  (reference: http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/BFG9000)

Comment: @PeterCordes Technically it stands for Big Falcon Rocket, but yes, it was deliberately chosen for the similar sound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFR_(rocket)

Comment: Perfect transportation system if you want to check the weather somewhere and tell your friends that you checked the weather there. Fabulous.

Comment: @reirab: Maybe if you live in say Miami :-)  But for anyone east of the Rockies, say, you'd basically have to either drive from your home, or get to an airport, spend hours going through boarding & security, fly to an airport near KSC, deplane and pick up luggage, travel to KFC, spend hours going through boarding & security there...  It's the same problem as with the Concorde: decreasing actual flying time doesn't shave all that much off total trip time.

Comment: @jamesqf ...it does if you save 16-28 hours and a stopover?

Comment: @jamesqf I live in TN. I could drive 11 hours to KSC and still get to Hong Kong faster with the rocket than the normal way. Last time I went there, it was well more than 24 hours from when I left home to arrival in HKG (and that was with no delays.) 19 hours of actual flight time, plus an hour drive to the airport, plus a layover, check-in, etc. I can get to KFC in about 10 minutes, though. They have pretty good chicken. The Concorde was an alternative to a 6-hour flight. This is talking about an alternative to 15+ hour flights, where the flying time actually is the majority of the trip.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain: But you could save a comparable amount of time by taking a direct flight instead.  Do you really think this rocket transportation system will go direct from where you are to where you want to go?  Especially when carrying a large number of passengers, which I understand is the plan.  How many people want to travel from say NYC to Hong Kong at any given time?  Not many, so you have to wait around to collect enough passengers to pay the costs.  The economics are like those of a private jet vs scheduled airline, but upped by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @reirab: Maybe YOU could do that trip in 11 hours, given a big enough gas tank and lots of coffee.  I think for most people it would be a two-day trip.  Google says about 14 hours drive time (not including fuel & rest stops), so not that far off the HK flight time.

Comment: @jamesqf There's daily or more flights/connections between all of the routes Musk showed in his graphic. 5 direct flights for NY to Hong Kong, not including connecting routes eg Emirates and other airlines that don't do direct. For 95% of the trips I take, what he's suggesting would be an order of magnitude quicker than presently available. Any A380 flight is a 500 odd passenger capacity,  and often a 8+ hour flight,  so most of those routes would be competitive.

Comment: @jamesqf Google says it's a bit over 10 hours from where I live to KSC. Judging from lots of personal experience driving from where I live to central Florida (most recently yesterday,) that's about right.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain: How many people on those daily flights are paying for a first-class ticket?  And how many of that small fraction are going to be able and willing to pay the orders of magnitude higher cost of a rocket flight? Then again, there's the issue of not being able to launch from anywhere near NYC or many if not all of those other places, due to noise and safety concerns.

Comment: You're assuming (and it is a big assumption), that noise/safety concerns might not be mitigated. Now you're talking about cost? IFF Musk is correct, cost will be competitive. So will time, even if you're 1 hour hyperlooping to a lauch/landing site at each end. But since you asked for numbers, you're talking around 90 between business and economy class for your average Emirates A380. More than enough to fold into 1 or 2 rocket flights per day.

Comment: By the way, lived near Aldershot MOD/RAF/whatever they call it now, for a few years...the sonic booms weren't that much of an irritant. Have you ever heard a large jet or a fighter taking off...not exactly quiet. Not on the order of a rocket launch, but they're working on bringing engine/sonic boom noise down, and there's no foreseeable reason why similar research cannot mitigate rocket noise. Some kind of interference/damping, channelling into absorbent materials below the launchsite etc are all valid ideas.

Answer (score 22):

The only way to get anything that far that quickly is to send it into space, and that's exactly what Musk is suggesting. The BFR will launch a passenger carrying spacecraft out of the atmosphere and into a sub-orbital path, it will re-enter the atmosphere close to its destination. Rockets launch pretty much straight up and a sonic boom would have to compete with the rocket itself on noise. Once above the atmosphere there is no sonic boom because there is no air.

On re-entry all spacecraft create a sonic boom, for most of the re-entry this is  inaudible from the ground because the air is extremely thin, once in the lower atmosphere it gets louder. By the time the spacecraft gets low enough to create a really big sonic boom it's usually at a subsonic speed and would not make any boom at all. The shuttle and Apollo spacecraft both created sonic booms on re-entry, that's covered in this [Space SE Question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/when-does-an-aerobraking-space-craft-create-a-sonic-boom).

So, are sonic booms a problem in this idea? It depends, the space shuttle re-entered over the continental US many times and it never bothered anyone, but if it was happening a few times a day it might be a problem. You could get around that for the most part by re-entering over sparsely populated areas or the ocean.

More likely it's not the sonic booms that people won't want from a noise perspective, but the launches.

Answer (score 2):

Since the rocket will be traveling through space, there will be no noise on the ground during cruise.

As pointed by @DeltaLima in the comments, a lot of satellites are crossing the sky above us at this very moment. Since there is no air in space, no sound can be heard, especially from that distance.

The only noisy parts will be the takeoff and landing, but with carefully selected location, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Landing presumably won't be supersonic, so booms shouldn't be an issue there. 'Takeoff' (i.e. launch) will be noisy regardless of the boom.

Comment: @reirab *landing* is subsonic, but part of *approach* is supersonic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True, but, if it's anything like the Space Shuttle, that part of the approach will be too high to matter. Not sure about SpaceX's rocket, but the Space Shuttle descended _extremely_ quickly. It was like piloting a brick.

Comment: "a carefully selected location" for takeoff would have to be far from a densely populated area. Which pretty much defeats the point of "getting quickly from A to B". You would first have to get from your area of population to A which is "far from civilization". Seems like a pretty deep flaw in the plan. I hope they have thought this through.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it. Sonic boom/s may well occur but likely (or could be specifically planned by routing etc) to occur in upper atmosphere/away from population centers.

The rocket seems planned to take off from an island or floating structure (judging by the graphics, which showed a ferry to the launch site), which could easily be tens of miles away from land if that were an issue. That distance might be enough to mitigate a lot of the launch noise.

As for landing, it's probably possible to come into landing along such a trajectory as to not be near a city when excessive noise will be produced, either by coming in over the ocean (in the graphic's example) or even by 's'turning around populated areas, shedding speed in the same trajectory (the space shuttle bled off speed this way, I believe).

Note that military craft produce booms frequently (although AFAIK they try to limit proximity to populated areas), as does any orbital (and most suborbital, although not so many of those fly these days) rocket, and Concorde produced booms. So:

> Will it ever be allowed to fly across the US above the oceans and
>   anywhere at those speeds

I don't see potential booms impacting whether it is allowed at all. Where it is permitted to be routed/produce booms, and how frequently, are open questions.

Comment: The US banned commercial supersonic aircraft flying across land in the US specifically because of the Concorde, so in theory any supersonic "aircraft" produced by Space X flying above the US would also be prohibited if not by the same rule, by the same concerns. However it's a rocket and not an aircraft and so doesn't make the same sonic booms. Perhaps more importantly this shouldn't also be an issue because it's made by a US company, not a foreign one, and Boeing has no plans to make it's own competing version.

Comment: Rules can be changed. NASA has been working on technologies to minimise sonic boom related disturbance as part of its research into hypersonic aircraft, so there's some mitigation possibilities there too.

Comment: Yes, I explained why I think the rules would be changed if necessary.

Comment: @RossRidge Those rules only apply if you're flying in U.S. national airspace. Rockets don't do that, except during launch. Completely different sets of rules involved.

Comment: @reirab Yes, as I said "it's a rocket and not an aircraft".

Comment: Taking off from an island or floating platform doesn't do a whole lot to reduce journey times unless you live on the coast...

Comment: ...a lot of the time if you're flying long distance, you already travel to a coastal city for your connection, right?